# Render/return a loading page during lengthy Flask task, and on finish render another HTML page with results?

Tags: java, html, flask

I have a Flask webapp which is connected through Heroku which have a timeout on returning a page of about 30 seconds.

In few of my routes I need to download stock data which on some occasions can take more then 30 seconds, which cause the website to crash.

I need to assign a thread/process to the downloading function, than return a loading HTML page, and when the thread/process finishs I'll need to update the HTML page to show the results.

I knocked an example for my code in route:
(some variables were omitted for simplicity but appear on the HTML example below)

```
df = yf.download(symbols, start=request.form.get("start"), end=request.form.get("end"), auto_adjust = False, prepost = False, threads = True, proxy = None)["Adj Close"].dropna(axis=1, how='all')

for col in df.columns:
            if col.endswith(".L"):
                df.loc[:,col] = df.loc[:,col]*GBPtoUSD()
        latest_prices2 = df.iloc[-1]  # prices as of the day you are allocating
        if float(request.form.get("funds")) <= 0 or float(request.form.get("funds")) == " ":
            flash("Amount need to be a positive number")
            return redirect("/build")
        if float(request.form.get("funds")) < float(latest_prices.min()):
            flash("Amount is not high enough to cover the lowest priced stock")
            return redirect("/build")
        da = DiscreteAllocation(weights, latest_prices, total_portfolio_value=float(request.form.get("funds")))
        alloc2, leftover2 = da.lp_portfolio()
        session['alloc2']=alloc2
        session['latest_prices2']=latest_prices2
        mc.delete("symbols")
        return render_template ("built.html",alloc2=alloc2,leftover2=leftover2)
```

built.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Built
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("btn2").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("btn3").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("btn4").disabled = true;
    }
</script>



<div align="left"; class="child"; id="plotly-timeseries"></div>
<script>
var graph = {{ plot_json | safe }};
Plotly.plot('plotly-timeseries', graph, {});
</script>


<h4>Efficient semi-variance optimization</h4>
<p>Here we will minimise the portfolio semivariance (i.e downside volatility) subject to a return constraint ({{ ret }}%).</p>
<p>Expected annual return: {{ "%.2f" | format(perf2[0]*100) }}%</p>
<p>Annual semi-deviation: {{ "%.2f" | format(perf2[1]*100) }}%</p>
<p>Sortino Ratio: {{ "%.2f" | format(perf2[2]) }}</p>
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <h4>If you happy with the suggested portfolio, the following output will show how many stocks to buy and the leftover funds</h4>
  <p style="color:red;">Please note that the symbols prices may change between the time it takes to choose your portfolio</p>
  <P>{{ alloc2 }}</P>
  <p>{{ "$%.2f" | format(leftover2) }} leftover</p>
  <form action="/allocation2" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="this.form.submit(); myFunction()" id="btn3">Buy</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any suggestion on what will be the best practice to solve this issue?

There is a similar question here [Flask render loading page until results are generated (then load result page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199280/flask-render-loading-page-until-results-are-generated-then-load-result-page)

But how do I implement the loading page and update the HTML when the results from the thread arrive?

Comment: This is very interesting question. You don't need to have a separate thread for this. The front end sends the request to flask. The route function will prepare the download and notifies the user

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting question.  First you don't know if the user will have the page/browser open after 30s. You don't need to have a separate thread for this. The front end (html/javascript) sends the request to flask. The route function will prepare the download and notifies the user using any notification method such as email or browser notification. If you're sure that the user will keep the browser open you can use flask-socketIO:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

The application must serve a page to the client that loads the Socket.IO library and establishes a connection:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
</script>
```

Now you can send a message from flask back to the browser:

```
from flask_socketio import send, emit

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    # handle the message received from the client
    # send back data
    send("message handled ...")
```

If you decide to adapt this method to solve you problem here is the documentations link [Flask-SoketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I am trying to keep it as simple as possible, and working with socketIO before I know that at least for me I find it a bit problematic. I think that the correct way to solve this is to have the button on build.html submit an html loading page(loading.html) which on loading.html there will a function to call the flask route.

Comment: I tried to call the route from the loading.html on page load, but now all the values that need to be passed to the route from the form on the build.html page are lost.